# What testing strategy should I use to test tournament algorithm

Tags: laravel, testing

I have a tournament algorithm that generate trees depending on several factors, like:

- hasPreliminary
- how much player can pass preliminary
- tournamentType ( singleElim, doubleElim, Playoff, etc )
- etc.

My question is about testing strategy ?

Should I test all combinations? this would mean each factor I had would have a significant impact on the tests duration

Should I test only a limited set of combination ? If so, I would not be sure it passes all the cases

Should I test all cases? For example, odd, pair, primal number, etc...

Should I test statically? Defining the result in all case? But for each factor I add, static result will be bigger and bigger

What should be the best trade-off to test such system?

Answer (score 0):

If your input domain's too large, first test with limited set of combinations instead of exhaustive testing 
Check equivalence partitioning and/or orthogonal array testing